# Swift detect motion activity in background

Tags: ios, swift, core-motion

I want to detect motion activity when app is pause (not stop).
I used this code and it working if user use app:

```swift
let isActivityAvailable = CMMotionActivityManager.isActivityAvailable()
if isActivityAvailable {
    CMMotionActivityManager().startActivityUpdates(to: OperationQueue.main) { (motionActivity) in
        if (motionActivity!.confidence.rawValue > 0) {
            if (motionActivity?.walking)! {
                print("User is walking")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean detect motion when app is in the background?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apps can be in several states:

1. Running in the foreground
2. Running in the background (actively performing background tasks)
3. Suspended (still in memory but not getting processor time.)
4. Terminated. Suspended apps can be terminated at any time without warning.

Only the first 2 states will receive motion updates. To quote the docs:

> ...updates are not delivered while your app is suspended.

Apps only stay in state 2 (running in background) for a few seconds when the user swaps them out or locks their phone, unless you ask for background time. Background time is limited to a short interval (3 minutes?) except for a small set of app types like music players and turn-by-turn navigation apps.

Because of these things, the short answer is no, you can't receive motion updates while your app "is pause" because paused becomes suspended.

For your own use (or perhaps internal enterprise use) you could set up an app as a music player and have it receive motion updates continuously, but such an app would be rejected in app store review.